# cardano_serialization_lib + GeneralTransactionMetadata error

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-serialization-lib

### help
const METADATA = {
[policy.id]: {
[name.slice(0,32)]: {
...inputData.metadata
}
}
}

const generalMetadata = Loader.Cardano.GeneralTransactionMetadata.new()
generalMetadata.insert(
Loader.Cardano.BigNum.from_str("721"),
Loader.Cardano.encode_json_str_to_metadatum(JSON.stringify(metadata))
)
console.log(generalMetadata)
_metadata = Loader.Cardano.TransactionMetadata.new(generalMetadata)
rawTxBody.set_metadata_hash(Loader.Cardano.hash_metadata(_metadata))

thank.

Answer (score 0):

In the Alonzo update TransactionMetadata renamed to AuxiliaryData,
As you can see here

https://github.com/Emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib/releases

you should change this as well as some other definitions.

Good luck!